# Impossibily to run Jupyter notebook from Windows start menu and required tokens

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, token

I am a novice in the use of Python and I am using PandasBiogeme to estimate discrete choice models.

My issue is related to the Jupyter notebook. Usually when I wish to use it, I select it from the start menu of Windows 7 and automatically a new tab opens up in Chrome.

Yesterday, actually by not knowing exactly why, I logged out from Jupyter notebook and today when I launched it from the start menu the following error message appeared:

[image]

I thus decided to reinstall Anaconda, and PandasBiogeme and to update both of them.

Now when I wish to open Jupyter notebook from the start menu a prompt menu appears and suddenly disappears. Therefore I need to open the Anaconda Powershell and type

```
jupyter notebook
```

Yet, when I do this I receive the same error message I reported above

I typed in the second URL and I was then able to work again.

Yet, when I close Jupyter notebook and try to launch it again the same problem arises and I have to insert again 'a' token. I wrote 'a' token, because if I select by chance the token reported at the following URL (which has nothing to do with my work)

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html

namely, this one:

http://localhost:8888/?token=c8de56fa4deed24899803e93c227592aef6538f93025fe01

and then Jupyter notebook works and I can carry out my estimation.

I read different posts on the possibility to set a password to avoid problems related to tokens, but only the first time I inserted the token I had the option to insert a password in in a html page, but I decided not to do it. Now I believe it could be the case.

This is something that happened overnight, without, I believe, my doing anything specifically.

This issue is driving me crazy and I would be thankful if any of you had a potential suggestion.

Many thanks.
Marco